# About embedded firmware development

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, hardware, microcontroller

In the past few days I found how important is RTOS layer on the top of the embedded hardware.
My question is : 
Is there any bifurcation between device driver (written in C directly burned over the microcontroller) 
And the Linux Device driver ?

Comment: A driver is merely some code which talks directly to hardware, then provides some manner of abstraction layer (HAL) to the application, so that is can access that hardware without knowing the dirty details. Otherwise there will be a big difference between a driver for a microcontroller and a driver for Linux - in the latter case you have all manner of OS-specifics and APIs to consider, so that the driver must be in a certain format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little broad, but an answer, a little broad itself, can be given.

The broadness comes from the fact that "embedded hardware" is not a precise term. That hardware ranges from 4 bit microcontrollers, or 8 pins ones, up to big CPUs which have many points in common with typical processors used tipically on linux machines (desktop and servers). Linux itself can be tailored up to the point it does not resemble a normal operating system anymore.

Anyway, a few things, generally acceptable, can be the following. Linux is *not*, in its "plain" version, a real time operating system - with the term RTOS instead, the "real time" part is implied. So, this can be one bifurcation. But the most important thing, I think, is that embedded firmware tries to address the hardware *and* the task to be done without anything else added. Linux O.S. instead is general purpose - it means that it offers a lot of services and functionalities that, in many cases, are not needed and only give more cost, less performances, more complication.

Often, in a small or medium embedded system, there is not even a "driver": the hardware and the application talk directly to each other. Of course, when the hardware is (more or less) standard (like a USB port, a ethernet controller, a serial port), the programming framework can provide ready-to-use software that sometimes is called "driver" - but very often it is not a driver, but simply a library with a set of functions to initialize the device, and exchange data. The application uses those library routines to directly manage the device. The O.S. layer is not present or, if the programmer wants to use an RTOS, he must check that there are no problems.

A Linux driver is not targeted to the application, but to the kernel. And the application seldom talks to the driver - it uses instead a uniform language (tipically "file system idiom") to talk to the kernel, which in turns calls the driver on behalf of the application.

A simple example I know very well is a serial port. Under Linux you open a file (may be /dev/ttyS0), use some IOCTL and alike to set it up, and then start to read and write to the file. You don't even care that there is a driver in the middle, and the driver was written without knowledge of the application - the driver only interacts with the kernel.

In many embedded cases instead, you set up the serial port writing directly to the hardware registers; you then write two interrupt routines which read and write to the serial port, getting and putting data from/into ram buffers. The application reads and writes data directly to those buffers. Special events (or not so special ones) can be signaled directly from the interrupt handlers to the application. Sometimes I implement the serial protocol (checksum, packets, sequences) directly in the interrupt routine. It is faster, and simpler, and uses less resources. But clearly this piece of software is no more a "driver" in the common sense.

Hope this answer explains at least a part of the whole picture, which is very large.